# Kubernetes : Expose service internally within VPN

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, kops

I've created kubernetes cluster using kops

```
kops create cluster \
    --dns-zone=vpc.abc.in \
    --master-zones=ap-southeast-1a,ap-southeast-1b,ap-southeast-1c \
    --zones=ap-southeast-1a,ap-southeast-1b,ap-southeast-1c \
    --node-count 3 \
    --topology private \
    --networking flannel-vxlan \
    --node-size=t2.medium \
    --master-size=t2.micro \
    ${NAME}
```

I'm using private topology and internal loadbalancer.

Whenever I create service of type=LoadBalancer it creates a public facing ELB and url is accessible publically.

I want to deploy Elastic Search and kibana and make it available only inside VPN. We already have VPN setup.

How to make service accessible within the VPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following annotation to your service definition:

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: '"true"'
```

Full example:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: '"true"'
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 9376
  type: LoadBalancer
```

This will provision an internal ELB rather than external.

Comment: I did try this and it worked... This creates internal load balancer for service... Thanks